# MySQL Concat and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 Tables: `People` and `Writings`. I would like to get list of 3 people who wrote the most books.

Tables: 
[image]

I would like to get top 3 people who have most books written (book = theme). And they should be ordered from the most to least (I mean those 3 people).

I tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT People.Name, People.Secondname,     
  People.City, COUNT( Writings.Author)  AS Kiekis       
FROM Writings, People 
WHERE  CONCAT (People.Name, ' ',People.Secondname) = Writings.Author 
GROUP BY Kiekis DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: How is `Pranesimai` and `Dalyviai` related to each other?

Comment: sorry i forgot to change names, one quick second. Really bald mistake..

Comment: When you use the limit keyword, you really want to have an order by clause.

Comment: why 2 copies of text?

Comment: Ok, variables are right now :) Dan Bracuk - What do you mean by Clause?

Comment: Refer to alex's answer.  Notice what he has on the line above limt 3?  That's an order by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Author, COUNT(*)
FROM People, Writings 
WHERE CONCAT (People.Name, ' ',People.Secondname) = Writings.Author 
GROUP BY Author 
ORdER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

But really weird join between tables, I mean it would be better to use author_id in 1st table.

Comment: Yeah, first time I got something like this and just tryed to Improvise, but ofcourse I failed... let me try Your way :) Ill reply soon

Comment: THANKS a lot :) It helped Me big time :) Have a nice day Sir ^^ And ofcourse thanks to all others who try'ed to help :)

Comment: One more question, how to change Count(*) into Kiekis? (just the name change)

Comment: ok, now i feel stupid.... Need to sleep for some time :) Thanks for quick response :)